# How to read property file at the time of flow start in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am creating a flow which contains mainly 2 node:
1) WMB node - it picks message from MQ
2) Java Node -  It transform and process the message.

I have created one property file which contains some values to implement the Business Logic. During the execution of flow, my java classes read that property file.

So as per the current implementation, java classes are loading property file whenever a new message is coming in the MQ. So in this way if 'n' messages come in the queue, the flow read property file 'n' times.

But I want that the property file should be read only once, at the time when we are deploying/restarting the flow not in the each execution of flow.

Just FYI, I am not using the spring framework in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can declare the following in your Mule flow and you don't require Spring beans for that :-

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:yourpropertFileName.properties"/>
```

It will be read only once after the server starts/restarts

**UPDATE**

Suppose you have a properties file named as `yourpropertFileName.properties` and you have defined following Keys and Values in it :-

```
message1=This is message1 value
message2=This is message2 value
```

Now you can use it in Mule Flow like the following :-

```
<logger message="${message1}" level="INFO" />
<logger message="${message2}" level="INFO" />
```

As you can see I have read the Keys and values from the properties file and used it in logger in Mule Config file .. Same way you can use the Keys from properties file in any Mule component you want

**UPDATED:-**
Here is a sample Java class that reads value from properties file .. You can modify as per your requirement :-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

    public class SampleJavaClass extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

        Properties prop = new Properties(); //Creating property file object read File attachment path from property file
        InputStream input = null; // To read property file path

        @Override
        public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding)
                throws TransformerException {

             try {
                input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("yourpropertFileName.properties"); // Property file path in classpath
                 prop.load(input); // get and load the property file
                String msg1=prop.getProperty("message1");
                String msg2=prop.getProperty("message2");
                System.out.println("Key1 from Prop file "+msg1);
                System.out.println("Key2 from Prop file "+msg2);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              return message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, Mule uses the Spring Framework internally.  Spring is used to load the Mule configuration file, so you can add the context namespace directly.

Comment: @Anirban: Thanks for your reply. How can I use the key of this property file in my Java Code. Please help.

Comment: I have updated my answer .. Pls accept the answer if you find useful

Comment: @Anirban: Appreciating your quick turnaround and help on this topic. This way I can use property file in the flow e.g configure timeout in file node, Queue Name in WMQ node.
But here My question is how I can use the property file values inside the Java Program (which I have written inside the Java Node), as My property file having lots of key and I want to use those at run time. I can not give those all in the flow XML.
Please help me.

Comment: Pls check my answer .. update with sample Java class accessing properties file values .. Pls accept my answer if you find this helpful

Comment: @Anirban: I am already using this workaround, but in this way we need to load property file in each execution of flow. e.g if there is 100 message in queue and each message call the Java program while processing then property file will be load 100 times. which is not a correct approach.
I want the property file should be load once when the flow will be deployed and in java program we only fetch the value. The first solution which you have suggested, I also using already that in my flow but I am unable to use in the java code.
Hope I am clear on my point
Many thnx 4 ur quick replies :)

Comment: See .. What I feel is the approach you are trying is wrong .. If you load the properties file in Your Mule config you can use it in entire Mule but not in a Java class(Until you pass it to java class). The code which I have shown there is a way to read the properties file in Java class .. You should understand reading properties in Mule and Java class are independent approach ... What you can do is make a common java class (like util) where you load the properties file once and call a method of that Java class in other Java classes where you required to get the key values of properties file ..

Comment: @Anirban: Thnx for the continuous discussion on my query. I am a newbie in this tech.
This is what I want to explain you that I can not use mule config file in Java Code, so is there any approach that I can use other property file the same way mule config file is working. I want to load that property file at time of flow deployment. Making Java Utill class is not the solution as it will be called again and again whenever message will be reached in the WMQ
It seems I need to follow singleton pattern as workaround to avoid property file loading in each message arrival which I really don't want.

Comment: Could you please provide your answer on the another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798383/what-should-be-the-return-value-for-transformmessage-method-in-mule